# Is it possible to run a ServiceHost where they type has a generic?

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, app-config, servicehost

For example

```
        // Create a ServiceHost for the Service type and 
        // provide the base address.
        mServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(T));

        // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
        // listening for messages.
        mServiceHost.Open();
```

where in this case T is TransactionProcessingService.

So far I am getting an error with the app config and not sure how I should modify it:

> Service
>   'TransactionProcessingWindowsService.TransactionProcessingService`1[[Common.TransactionProcessing,
>   Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has
>   zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because
>   no configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   service element matching the service name could be found in the
>   configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the
>   service element.

Here's how I tried to set up my config

```xml
      <service name="TransactionProcessingWindowsService.TransactionProcessingService&lt;TransactionProcessingWindowsService.TransactionProcessing&gt;"
           behaviorConfiguration="TransactionProcessingServiceBehavior">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/TransactionProcessingService/service"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="TransactionProcessingWindowsService.ITransactionProcessingService" />
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception details show you what service name should be used. Try this:

```
<service name="TransactionProcessingWindowsService.TransactionProcessingService`1[[Common.TransactionProcessing, Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"
         behaviorConfiguration="TransactionProcessingServiceBehavior">
```

but that is not cool, as you need to update config file each time you changing the assembly version or sign it.

Comment: I didn't think you could actually specify a name like that.

Comment: Unless its strongly named, Version, Culture, and PublicKeyToken are optional. Just don't add them.

Comment: So then, would the name would be name="TransactionProcessingWindowsService.TransactionProcessingService`1[[Common.TransactionProcessing, Common]]"

Answer (score 0):

Your config file has an endpoint for ITransactionProcessingService, but not for TransactionProcessingService.

Because you are using generics, T can be anything (or whatever you limit it to).  But you need to have an endpoint defined for whatever you use as T.

I would recommend an interface instead of a generic.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was trying the generic because I already had an Interface, but needed a common base class for the common functionality. So, I was trying this:

```
public class TransactionProcessingService<T> : ITransactionProcessingService where T : BaseProgram
```

Because I wanted to have the common functionality and properties from BaseProgram. I couldn't inherit from 2 interfaces or an interface and a class because I could only have one wsHttpBinding binding endpoint. I ended up going back to

```
public class TransactionProcessingService : ITransactionProcessingService
```

and

```
public class MyServiceBase<T, U> : ServiceBase where U : BaseProgram, new()
```

where MyServiceBase provides a static property that just provides access to the property in the static instance of U.

```
private static U mProcess;
protected ServiceHost mServiceHost = null;
public static int StatusCheckFrequency
{
    get { return mProcess.StatusCheckFrequency; }
    set { mProcess.StatusCheckFrequency = value; }
}
```

This works because I only intend to have one instance of each service running on a machine.

I'll give ie. the answer because it appears to answer my question, even though I didn't end up trying it.